# External monitors not remaining off after screen lock/suspend

Tags: display, suspend, monitor, 23.10, lock

I am using Ubuntu 23.10 on a laptop and a desktop. The external monitors are on separate rigs (one on my downstairs laptop setup) and one permanently connected to my upsatiars desktop).
On both, when I lock my screen (e.g. `Super` + `L`), the external monitors initially turn off, but then come back on to the lock screen and stay like that, or cycle through the monitors' "no input found" automatic suspend function.

The same thing happens when I suspend my laptop - after a few seconds, the external monitor comes back on to the lock screen.
When I suspend my desktop, the "no input found" cycles every 10 or so seconds and never goes into the monitor's suspended state.